# Spring Boot @OneToMany where data in M side is not not relevant and used only for internal logging/auditing

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

In Spring Boot JPA we often have entity relationships like `@OneToMany` to map to database relationships like 1:M.

This is fine if we have a case like entities like Car and Part where Car is 1 side of relationship and Part is M side of relationship.  In such case, this is fine as the data in both tables is "related" and we want to insert or fetch related data at once from both tables.

In this case, our Car entity would have OneToMany like:

```
@Entity(name = "car")
public class CarEntity {
  ...
  @Id @GeneratedValue(...)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<PartEntity> parts;
}
```

and Part entity would have ManyToOne like:

```
@Entity(name = "part")
public class PartEntity {
  ...
   
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
  private CarEntity carDetails;
}
```

, and this is fine.

To persist date, we would have to provide a JSON payload holding data for **both** Car and its Parts in the payload in order to save both Car and Parts:

```
{
    "vendor": "Toyota",
    "model": "Camry"
    "parts": [
      {
          "gasket": "A103",
          "price": "16"
      },
      {
          "tire": "Good year",
          "price": "149"
      }
    ]
}
```

,this would persist both car and its parts to repository.

Same when retrieving.  Retrieving a Car would also retrieve its Parts.

This is all clear.

However, we might have a 1:M relation where data in M is "kind of unrelated" to data in 1 side of relationship.

For example let's say we are logging events for say audit purposes.  Each event is logged in EVENT table.  But we also want to forward this event to some downstream API, so we also log if the event was sent to this downstream API in EVENT_LOG table.

So, we have EVENT : EVENT_LOG 1:M relationship where one EVENT can have multiple EVENT_LOGs.  In this case, EVENT_LOG is "unrelevant" as it is just data for logging / auditing purposes and is not supposed to be part of JSON payload in neither POST nor GET requests.

Let's say we have these table definitions:

```
EVENT[ID (PK), NAME, DATE]
EVENT_LOG[ID (PK), EVENT_ID (FK), SENT, DATE]
```

above, PKs and DATEs fields are handled by the database, and SENT field is defaulted to 0 for not sent yet (1 = sent).  For example:

```
EVENT     [1, 'save_data_event', 2022-10-12T15:17:001]
EVENT_LOG [1, 1, 0, 2022-10-12T15:17:002]  // 0 = default (not sent)
```

Here, we would like to send JSON payload containing **only** relevant EVENT data:

```
{
    "vendor": "some_data_event"
}
```

This would populate EVENT table like above.  However, using the above @OneToMany relationship in Entity classes, it would not populate data in EVENT_LOG which is **not** what we want.  We want them both populated.

Similarly, when fetching data, we want only relevant data from EVENT table as EVENT_LOG data is not of interest and it should not be included in JSON GET payload.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Jackson you may use `@JsonIgnore` to ignore attributes for JSON generation.

I consider the above a hack.
The proper way to do things is to break your domain models into aggregates as recommended by Domain Driven Design and us only ids to reference between aggregates. [I wrote an article about this in the context of Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates), but the concept can and arguably should be applied to JPA as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the `@JsonIgnore` annotation would then be used  to annotate `private List<PartEntity> parts; field in the `CarEntity` example above?

Comment: And also, using `@JsonIgnore` might solve GET issue and ignore that field when sending response.  But the issue with POST still remains